# Execute mongoDB shell like query using a java class

Tags: java, mongodb, jackson, mongo-java, mongo-jackson-mapper

Using a java class i want to execute MongoDB shell query stored in a String variable.Currently i am using the following code.

```
String query="db.INSTANT.insert( { item: 'card', qty: 12 } )";
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("mydb");
db.eval(query);
```

The above code works fine for insert. But i want to execute find statement like `query=db.INSTANT.find({"item":"card"})`.Is there any way to execute this query and print the collection set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the function of [`eval`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/#db.eval) has been deprecated since version 3.0.

The helper db.eval() in the Java Driver wraps the mongo eval command, So you can evaluate JavaScript code this way

```
String query="db.INSTANT.find( { item: 'card', qty: 12 } ).toArray()";
```

Comment: I want to print the result set. Can you please demonstrate it with a sample code.

Comment: You can cast result as (List<BasicDBObject>) db.eval(query);

Comment: I typecasted like  "List<BasicDBObject> ob =(List<BasicDBObject>) db.eval(query);" and I am getting this exception. "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to java.util.List
 at com.sixdee.demo.MongoQuery.main(MongoQuery.java:23)". What goes wrong in it.

Comment: Did you add the "toArray()"?

Comment: Thank you.It is working. Is there any another way to do this. My intention is to execute normal MongoDB query using a java class.